# Finding the values of $\cos \frac{n\pi}{2}$ and $\sin \frac{n\pi}{2}$.

Tags: trigonometry

i know that the values of $\cos n\pi=(-1)^{n}$ and $\sin n\pi=0$. Now i want to know that what is the general expressions of $\cos \frac{n\pi}{2}$ and $\sin \frac{n\pi}{2}$.

Comment: When $n$ is even you already have the answer. When $n$ is odd try working a few out, the pattern is very easy to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two cases:

1. $n$ is even, write it as $2k$ and then you have $\cos(k\pi)$ and $\sin(k\pi)$ which you already know.
2. $n$ is odd, write it as $2k+1$ and then you have $\cos(k\pi+\frac\pi2)$ and $\sin(k\pi+\frac\pi2)$. Recall that $\sin(x)=\cos(x+\frac\pi2)$, and deduce from the previous case what the values are.

Comment: @AsafFaragila sir i want to know the general expression.

Comment: As sir i found that general expression for $\sin \frac{n\pi}{2}=(-1)^{[\frac{n}{2}]}$. i want to know for $\cos (\frac{n\pi}{2})$.

Comment: @Vishal: No, this expression is wrong. For $n=2$ it is false. If you do find a general expression for $\sin(\frac{n\pi}2)$ then $\cos(\frac{n\pi}2)=\sin(\frac{(n+1)\pi}2)$, as the second sentence I wrote says.

Comment: @Vishal : I added general expression for $\sin$ and $\cos$ in my answer.

Answer (score 12):

Using identities $\sin(x)^2 = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$ and $\cos(x)^2 = \frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$ we get

$$ \left(\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\right)^2 = \frac{1 - \cos(n\pi)}{2} = \frac{1 - (-1)^n}{2} $$
$$ \left(\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\right)^2 = \frac{1 + \cos(n\pi)}{2} = \frac{1 + (-1)^n}{2}$$

Thus :

- $\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right) = 0$ if $n$ is even and $\pm 1$ if odd
- $\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right) = 0$ if $n$ is odd and $\pm 1$ if even

To conclude we have to solve $\pm 1$ cases.

- $\cos$ case : $n$ is even, $n=2p$. Then 
  $$\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right) = \cos\left(p\pi\right) = (-1)^p$$
  So the result is $1$ if $p$ is even, $-1$ if odd
- $\sin$ case : $n$ is odd, $n=2p+1$. Then 
  $$\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right) =\sin\left(p\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \cos\left(p\pi\right) = (-1)^p$$
  So $1$ if $p$ is even, $-1$ if odd

Finally we get the following general expressions :

$$ \cos\left( \frac{n\pi}{2}\right) = (-1)^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \left( \frac{1+(-1)^n}{2} \right) $$
$$ \sin\left( \frac{n\pi}{2}\right) = (-1)^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \left( \frac{1-(-1)^n}{2} \right) $$

Comment: I think that for $n=3$ you have that $\sin(\frac{n\pi}2)\neq 1$.

Comment: I agree that the final expressions are correct, but I would like to add that the floor functions are unnecessary. For the cosine, the floor can be omitted, and for the sine, floor($n/2$) can be replaced with $(n-1)/2$, and the expressions still hold.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \cos\frac{n\pi}{2}=\{1,0,-1,0\}=2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor+2\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{4}\right\rfloor+1-n$

$\displaystyle \sin\frac{n\pi}{2}=\{0,1,0,-1\}=n-2\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{4}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{n+2}{4}\right\rfloor$